# Why I'm getting a blank page in result instead of today's date in following PHP code?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've following small code snippet to display today's date and value of one variable but I'm getting the blank white page in result. Why so?

My code is as below:

```
<?php
  $form_data['trans_date'] = '12-11-2014';// Date format is MM-DD-YYYY i.e. 11th December 2014
  $newTransDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $form_data['trans_date']);
  $today_date = new DateTime('today');
  echo "Today Date ".$today_date; die;//Here I want to print today's date
  $form_data['trans_date'] = '12-11-2014';
  $newTransDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $form_data['trans_date']);
  $today_date = new DateTime('today');
  echo "Today Date ".$newTransDate."<br>"; die;//Here I wan tot print today's date
  echo "New Trans Date ".$newTransDate; die;//Here I wan tot print value of var $newTransDate
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: If it was you'd see why it's failing: **Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string...etc**

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PHP's `DateTime`, while outputting you need to define the output format.

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$now = new DateTime();

// Output
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```